# how to write multiple vtkUnstructuredGrid in one .vtu file

Tags: vtk

I want to write multiple unstructured grids in one .vtu file.

I tried below. MakeHexagonalPrism() and MakeHexahedron() return vtkSmartPointer type. 
The result is there was only one unstructured grid in the output file.

```
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter> writer =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter>::New();
  writer->SetFileName(filename.c_str());
  writer->SetInputData(MakeHexagonalPrism());
  writer->SetInputData(MakeHexahedron());
  writer->Write();
```

I also tried below. The type of cellArray1 and cellArray2  is vtkSmartPointer. The result is there was only one type of unstructured grid in the output file.

```
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid> unstructuredGrid =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid>::New();
  unstructuredGrid->SetPoints(points);
  unstructuredGrid->SetCells(VTK_TETRA, cellArray1);
  unstructuredGrid->SetCells(VTK_WEDGE, cellArray2);
```

I do not know how to write multiple unstructured grids in one .vtu file.
I'd be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by the documentation, the [vtkUnstructuredGrid](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkUnstructuredGrid.html) class is very versatile.

> dataset represents arbitrary combinations of all possible cell types

You could use the [vtkAppendFilter](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkAppendFilter.html) in order to append different data sets into one then write the output as a vtkUnstructuredGrid result in a .vtu file.

```
// create the append filter
vtkSmartPointer<vtkAppendFilter> append =
vtkSmartPointer<vtkAppendfilter>::New();

// add each data set
append->AddInputData(MakeHexagonalPrism());
append->AddInputData(MakeHexahedron());
append->Update();

// write the result
vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter> writer =
vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter>::New();
writer->SetFileName(filename.c_str());
writer->SetInputData(append->GetOutput());
```

**EDIT**: I added the missing `Update()` function call as suggested by Amit Singh

Comment: Thanks for answering. This looks simple, but did not work in my environment (vtk7.1). NumberOfCells in output.vtu was "0".

Comment: Maybe it is missing an `Update()` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. It worked! I added `append->Update();` after `append->AddInputData(MakeHexahedron());`.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the documentation for `vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter` available [here](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter.html)

> One unstructured grid input can be written into one file in any number
>   of streamed pieces (if supported by the rest of the pipeline).

So I think it is not possible to write multiple unstructured grid datasets to one file using this writer class.

Do you want multiple types of cells inside the same unstructured grid (which can be written to a single `.vtu` file) rather than multiple unstructured grids in the same `.vtu` file? If yes, you must first combine the two cell arrays into a single cell array and also create a `int` array which contains type of each cell in the total cell array. For example,

```
// Create a Type vector to store cell types
std::vector<int> types;

// Create a new cell array composed of cellArray1 and cellArray2
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> allCells = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();

// Traverse cellArray1 and add it's cells to allCells
vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList> nextCell =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList>::New();
cellArray1->InitTraversal()
while( cellArray1->GetNextCell( nextCell ) ){
    allCells->InsertNextCell( nextCell );
    types.push_back( VTK_TETRA );
}
// Traverse cellArray2 and add it's cells to allCells
cellArray2->InitTraversal()
while( cellArray2->GetNextCell( nextCell ) ){
    allCells->InsertNextCell( nextCell );
    types.push_back( VTK_WEDGE );
}

//Finally, set allCells to unstructuredGrid
unstructuredGrid->SetCells( &(types[0]), allCells );
```

Now when you write this unstructured grid to a `.vtu` file, I think you should have both wedge type and tetra type of cells in one file.

Comment: Thank you very much for fast and detailed answer. This worked!

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, kindly accept it.

Comment: I am sorry. I am grateful for your answer, but I prefer Guillaume Favelier's answer because of its simplicity.

Comment: No problem. Accept his answer.

Answer (score 1):

As of @Gruillaume Faveiler's suggestion, using "vtkAppendFilter", the attributes would be filtered under the rule that: only those attribute existing in all inserted unstructuredGrid can be kept in the saved data (e.g., ug1 and ug2 are two appended unstructuredGrid, attribute "hight" exists in the pointData of both ug1 and ug2, then "hight" will be still in append->GetOutPut() which is also an unstructuredGrid, otherwise not)

In most cases when you have some attributes not in common for all inserted unstructuredGrid (in paraview, they call them "partial" attributes), which will be erased by vtkAppendFilter.

Better way for these cases is to use **vtkMultiBlockDataSet** in companion with **vtkXMLMultiBlockDataWriter**. One vtu file will be there for each UnstructedGrid, and a vtm file (containing no data) will be created to collect all vtu files into a structure. borrowing the example from @Guillaume Favelier, there will be:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkMultiBlockDataSet> multiBlockDataSet = vtkSmartPointer<vtkMultiBlockDataSet>::New();

// add each data set
vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid> ug1 = MakeHexagonalPrism();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid> ug2 = MakeHexahedron();
multiBlockDataSet->SetBlock(0, ug1);
multiBlockDataSet->SetBlock(1, ug2);

// write the result
vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLMultiBlockDataWriter> writer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLMultiBlockDataWriter>::New();
writer->SetFileName(filename.c_str());
writer->SetInputData(multiBlockDataSet);
writer->Write();
```