# How to write vtkUnstructuredGrid with sharing coordinates

Tags: vtk

I'm trying to convert from data structure about mesh I made by myself to vtu format file. Thanks to the answer of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349086/how-to-write-multiple-vtkunstructuredgrid-in-one-vtu-file/47352162?noredirect=1#comment81724368_47352162) I still made, I was able to create vtu format files.

However, all points belonging to multiple cells were output to the file as many as the number of cells. (In output.vtu, NumberOfPoints="10648" NumberOfCells="1331". 1331 * 8 = 10648) And if I tried to see that file in paraview I could not open it.

I do not know how to write vtkUnstructuredGrid with sharing coordinates . I'd be grateful for any hints.

This is the code I wrote.

`MyMesh` contains cell and vertex information.

```
bool writeVtu(MyMesh *mesh, const char *path)
{
    // create the append filter
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkAppendFilter> append =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkAppendFilter>::New();

    // add each data set
    for(int i = 0; i < num_cell; i++)
    {
        append->AddInputData(addCell(mesh->cell(i)));
    }
    append->Update();

    // write the result
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter> writer =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter>::New();
    writer->SetFileName(path);
    writer->SetInputData(append->GetOutput());
    writer->Write();

    return true;
}

vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid>
  addCell(MyCell* cell)
{
    int numberOfVertices = cell->numVertices();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++){
        points->InsertNextPoint(cell->getVertex(i)->getxyz());
    }

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList> idList = vtkIdList::New();
    idList->SetNumberOfIds(numberOfVertices);
    for (vtkIdType i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++)
    {
        idList->SetId(i, i);
    }

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid> ug =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid>::New();
    ug->InsertNextCell(
        vtkCellType(cell->vtkType()) , idList);
    ug->SetPoints(points);
    return ug;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apriori, assuming `MyMesh` provide global identifiers for the vertices, you could do the following:

```
bool writeVtu(MyMesh *mesh, const char *path)
{
    // create the unstructured grid
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid> ug =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid>::New();

    // create the shared points structure
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> pts =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
    pts->SetNumberOfPoints(num_points);

    // add each cell
    for(int i = 0; i < num_cell; i++)
    {
        addCell(mesh->cell(i), ug, pts);
    }

    // add the points
    ug->SetPoints(pts);

    // write the result
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter> writer =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter>::New();
    writer->SetFileName(path);
    writer->SetInputData(ug);
    writer->Write();

    return true;
}

void addCell(MyCell *cell,
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid> ug,
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points)
{
    int numberOfVertices = cell->numVertices();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList> idList = vtkIdList::New();
    idList->SetNumberOfIds(numberOfVertices);
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++){
        int globalId = cell->getVertex(i)->getId();
        idList->SetId(i, globalId);
        points->SetPoint(globalId, cell->getVertex(i)->getxyz());
    }

    ug->InsertNextCell(
        vtkCellType(cell->vtkType()) , idList);
}
```

This version of `addCell` adds the topology and the geometry at the same time and the structure managing the points is allocated accordingly at the beginning.
Here, I did not use `vtkAppendFilter` because I think that one `vtkUnstructuredGrid` can do the same job (based on the original version of the code).

Please note that this code is untested so be aware that it can contain errors. A call to `ug->Allocate(num_cells)` before inserting the cells may be necessary.

**EDIT:** I modified the second argument of the function `SetId()` to `globalId` as suggested by R. Y

Comment: I am always grateful for your help. I will try this code on Monday. There is something I want to check, but I think that the second argument of `setId ()` in `addCell()` is not `i` but `globalId (= cell-> getVertex (i) -> getId () )`. What do you think?

Comment: You are right, in the version below, the new cells must use the global identifiers of the vertices.

Comment: Thanks, this code worked! Although it is not directly related to the question, the generated file could not be read in paraview 5.0, but it could be read in paraview 5.2. So it may be due to the version of paraview that I could not read the previously created file. I have not checked it because I deleted the file I made before. Anyway, It was good that I could solve the problem that the number of vertices does not match. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad to know that the original problem of duplicated points is solved and if my answer helped in some way to achieve this, feel free to accept it.